# jQuery UI Tooltip won't close after click on IE11

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, internet-explorer, tooltip, jquery-ui-dialog

I have the following code:

```
<a class="btnDelete" href="linkHere" onclick="OpenDialog(this); return false;" title="Delete">Delete</a>

function OpenDialog()
{
    $("#dialog-item-could-not-be-deleted").dialog({
        modal: true,
        title: 'Delete',
        zIndex: 10000,
        autoOpen: true,
        width: 'auto',
        resizable: false,
        closeText: 'Close',
        buttons: {
            OK: function ()
            {
                $(this).dialog("close");
                $('.btnDelete').tooltip("close");
            }
        },
        close: function (event, ui)
        {
            $(this).hide();
            $('.btnDelete').tooltip("close");
        }
    });
}
```

The code above isn't complete, but that's not the point.

The idea is that on Firefox, the tooltip closes after I call `$('.btnDelete').tooltip("close");`. On IE it doesn't.

I looked in the debugger and apparently it creates another instance of tooltip on dialog close.

On IE it loks something like this:

[image: tooltip]

I have no idea how to stop this.

The creation code for tooltips is this:

```
$('.btnDelete').tooltip().click(function ()
{
    $(this).tooltip("close");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution: `tabindex = -1`

```
<a tabindex="-1" title="Delete" class="btnDelete" onclick="OpenDialog(this, true); return false;" href=".../Delete/43">Delete</a>
```